# Dojo Select/Combobox widgets freeze the other elements click events

Tags: select, combobox, onclick, dojo

I noticed that after selecting an option from a dojo Select or Combobox widget, I am unable to click on any other element only after 2-3 seconds.
I feel that selecting an option just freezes(for 2 seconds) the click event of the other elements.

I removed all events from the Select/Combobo widget...

What could be the cause?

Comment: We can't help without code !!

Comment: This generally happens when a single action's event(s) is(are) taking too much time to execute. It would be great if you could share your code or provide a fiddle on which the issue is reproducible.